# What is the the solution for the error"Platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1?

Tags: linux, boot, debian-installer

I have been trying to install debian 8 to my laptop yet i could not because  i am getting errors like "**Platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1**" and **uncompression error**.

Comment: What make/model of laptop?

Comment: I did a web search for "Platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1" and got this page with a list of suggestions and links for further details. YMMV. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926738/cant-load-failed-to-claim-resource-1

Comment: It's quite likely that the `MSFT` error is not what prevents Debian from booting. The "uncompression error" (wherever that happens) is a more likely candidate. Please edit question with a description *where exactly* the boot process gets stuck. A complete list of the messages seen so far would also help.

Comment: Is the HDD failing? See [Uncompression error - System halted. Boot repair didn-t work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751624/uncompression-error-system-halted-boot-repair-didn-t-work)